# Symfony - Override field options (required = false to required = true)

Tags: php, jquery, symfony, symfony-forms

**I want to accomplish the following:**

```
FormType -> If my checkbox is checked, hide a normally required field and make it required = false, so I can submit my Form.
```

So I need to override a specific form field if my checkbox is checked. Example...

**Form:**

```
$builder->add(
    'checkbox',
    CheckboxType::class,
    [
        'label' => 'checkbox',
        'required' => false,
        'mapped' => false,
        'attr' => [
            'class' => 'checkbox',
        ]
    ]
);
```

**index:**

```
$('.checkbox').change(function () {
    if ($('.checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $(".end-date").hide();
    } else {
        $(".end-date").show();
    }
});
```

how do i continue?

i tried something like this (somehow it's not working):

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            $config = $form->get('what_ever_field')->getConfig();
            $options = $config->getOptions();

            $form->add(
                'what_ever_field',
                get_class($config->getType()->getInnerType()),
                array_replace(
                    $options,
                    [
                        'required' => false,
                    ]
                )
            );
        });
```

But it makes no sense because the checkbox and the listener have no relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it would be much easier to dynamically change the field's **required** attribute via JS after it's rendered on the page. You're half way there:

JS

```
$('.checkbox').change(function() {
    if ($('.checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $(".end-date").removeAttr("required");
        $(".end-date").hide();
    } else {
        $(".end-date").attr("required","required");
        $(".end-date").show();
    }
});
```

This JQuery code can be optimized, but that's about it. Hope it helped.